# Output updates only when I clear the filter in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am very new to Shiny and had a problem when trying to create a plot. The filter and the graph result work fine, but only after the partner is selected in the filter and then deselected again. The output does not update after selecting a partner in the filter immediately, but rather after deselecting it which is very weird. What am I doing wrong :( ? I am providing a piece of code below in case someone can help I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

```
#### 1) Loading the libraries -------------------------------------------------------

library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)


#### 2) Load the data ------------------------------------------------------------------

data<-structure(list(partner = c("park 1", "park 1", "park 1", "park 2", 
"park 2", "park 2", "park 3", "park 3", "park 3", "park 4", "park 4", 
"park 4", "park 5", "park 5", "park 5"), product = c("Children", 
"Adults", "Senior", "Children", "Adults", "Senior", "Children", 
"Adults", "Senior", "Children", "Adults", "Senior", "Children", 
"Adults", "Senior"), quantity = c(10, 15, 25, 35, 46, 21, 34, 
45, 64, 75, 34, 32, 67, 43, 23)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

#### a) header ----------------------------------------------------

header <- 
  dashboardHeader(title = "Analysis")

#### b) Sidebar -------------------------------------------------------


sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Update",tabName = "update",icon=icon("info"))))


body <- dashboardBody( 
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "update",
            fluidPage(
              selectInput("partner","Partner", 
                          choices=unique(data$partner)),
              plotOutput("plot1")))))

ui <- 
  dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data%>% 
      filter(partner %in% input$partner) %>%
      group_by(product) %>% 
      summarise(total=sum(quantity)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x=product,y=log(total))) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(fill=product),color="black",show.legend = F)+
      coord_flip()+
      theme_test()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: please add a reproducible example

Comment: I am going to guess that you are better of solving this filter and group by inside a reactive() function, it is more efficient if you have two plots, and it always works for me

Comment: Hi Bruno. Thank you so much for your reply. I added a reproducible example above. I also tried it with a reactive(), but still the same issue. Would you be so kind as to say how you would personally optimally do it? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you look into the dput function please, it really speed ups my copy and pasting of your code, plus where is the sidebar and header?

Comment: I edited the file above and also shared the data with dput(). Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The app works perfectly for me at least, try to restart r, try to run this code as a job, isolate your session because this seems fine

Comment: Thanks for your help @Bruno. It's working now :)